# What is the correct way to link Django Flatpages?

Tags: python, django, apache

I have Django 1.8.2 installed in a subdirectory on my server. It is configured with mod_wsgi.py and an Apache2 and is running properly.

The Django application is accessible under *https://example.com/django* and everything is configured and running fine.

Now I want to use Flatpages and link them in my templates. I do it like this:

```
<a href="/my-flatpage/">Awesome!</a>
```

This works on the dev server on my local machine. But when I deploy it on my server, clicking on the link results in this url: *https://example.com/my-flatpage/* which is natural, because this is how I referenced it in the `a` tag.

But how can I do it properly, no matter if django is stored in a subdirectory or not? I do not want to hardcode the subdirectory */django/*, because this is just a testing server. There must be a better solution than this. Can you explain me please, how I should link my flatpages in my templates? I think there must be a way to include the correct path to the flatpage, no matter if Django is stored in a subdirectory or in root.

I tried to give them names in *urls.py* and hardcoded the links. But the testing server was not able to produce the correct links (the local dev webserver provided by django did!) and I do not think it is a good solution to write the urls twice into my application (first in the definition of the flatpage, second in the *urls.py*). With the named urls I tried to link to the pages with

```
<a href="{% url 'my-flatpage' %}">Awesome!</a>
```

Worked locally, but not on the testing server.

I have Middleware enabled for Flatpages:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

I know that a link starting with */* refers to the root. Therefore it skips the subdirectory, where it is actually stored in. I just don't know how to make proper links even if Django is installed in a subdirectory.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the middleware, there's no good solution. When using the `urls.py`, it's easy: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/#using-the-urlconf

You can make them explicit:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages import views

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^about-us/$', views.flatpage, {'url': '/about-us/'}, name='about'),
    url(r'^license/$', views.flatpage, {'url': '/license/'}, name='license'),
]
```

Or just the view:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages import views

# Your other patterns here
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^(?P<url>.*/)$', views.flatpage, name='flatpage'),
]
```

Combined with urls like these:

```
<a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
<a href="{% url 'about' %}">License</a>
<a href="{% url 'flatpage' url='/some_other_page/' %}">Some other page</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I did not know that using middleware caused my trouble...

But I'd love to use the second option you mentioned: named catchall referencing with `{% url 'flatpage' url='my-flatpage' %}`. But when I use it on the Apache2 server, I get this error: `NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'flatpage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'url': u'/my-flatpage/'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` Do you have any ideas?